# Arch Linux guest (Virtualbox): vboxdrv.service fails at startup

Tags: arch-linux, systemd, virtualbox, dmesg, startx

I am running Windows 10 as a Virtualbox Host and Arch Linux as Guest.

During startup, `vboxdrv.service` fails. The tty starts fine, I can do everything inside it. However, `startx` leads to what I believe to be the normal stdout, but after that, nothing happens, I have no graphical interface, my i3wm does not start.

My guess is that this behaviour is linked to `vboxdrv.service` failing at startup.

Relevant information might be:

`systemctl status vboxdrv.service`:

```
vboxdrv.service - VirtualBox Linux kernel module
     Loaded: loaded (/opt/VirtualBox/vboxdrv.sh; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2020-04-05 11:25:10 CEST, 11 min ago
    Process: 359 ExecStart=/opt/VirtualBox/vboxdrv.sh start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Apr 05 11:25:08 archlinux-vm systemd[1]: Starting VirtualBox Linux kernel module...
Apr 05 11:25:10 archlinux-vm vboxdrv.sh[359]: vboxdrv.sh: Starting VirtualBox services.
Apr 05 11:25:10 archlinux-vm vboxdrv.sh[398]: Starting VirtualBox services.
Apr 05 11:25:10 archlinux-vm vboxdrv.sh[359]: vboxdrv.sh: failed: modprobe vboxpci failed. Please use 'dmesg' to find out why.
Apr 05 11:25:10 archlinux-vm systemd[1]: vboxdrv.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Apr 05 11:25:10 archlinux-vm systemd[1]: vboxdrv.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'
Apr 05 11:25:10 archlinux-vm systemd[1]: Failed to start VirtualBox Linux kernel module.
```

`dmesg | grep vboxpci` yields nothing.

`dmesg | grep vboxdrv`:

```
[    7.200636] vboxdrv: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
[    7.200840] vboxdrv: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - taintig kernel
[    7.209208] vboxcrv: Found 1 processor cores
[    7.246471] vboxdrv: TSC mode is Invariant, tentative frequency 2711995959 Hz
[    7.246472] vboxdrv: Successfully loaded version 6.1.4 (interface 0x002d0001)
```

`startx`:

```
X.Org X Server 1.20.8
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
Build Operating System: Linux Arch Linux
Current Operating System: Linux archlinux-vm 5.5.13-arch2-1 # SMP PREEMPT Mon, 30 Mar 2020 20:42:41 +0000 x86_64
Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-linux root=UUID=894e6e02-38f6-4798-b936-431c8287803a rw quiet
Build Date: 30 March 2020 05:05:45AM

Current version of pixman: 0.38.4
        Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
        to make sure that you have the latest version.
Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
        (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational, 
        (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
(==) Log file: "/home/[username]/.local/share/xorg/Xorg.0.log", Time: Sun Apr  5 11:25:30 2020
(==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
_
```

and blocking the tty.

`pacman -Qs virtualbox`:

```
local/virtualbox-guest-modules-arch 6.1.4-12
    Virtualbox guest kernel modules for Arch Kernel
local/virtualbox-guest-utils 6.1.4-5
    VirtualBox Guest userspace utilities
local/virtualbox-host-modules-arch 6.1.4-12
    Virtualbox host kernel modules for Arch Kernel
```

EDIT: I have updated the machine again (it asked me whether I want to replace virtualbox-guest-modules with linux, I gladly agreed in hope of fixing the problem with the update, but behaviour stays the same), new `pacman -Qs virtualbox`:

```
local/linux 5.6.2.arch1-2
    The Linux kernel and modules
local/virtualbox-guest-utils 6.1.4-5
    VirtualBox Guest userspace utilities
local/virtualbox-host-modules-arch 6.1.4-15
    Virtualbox host kernel modules for Arch Kernel
```

This has been happening for about two weeks now, probably after updating my machine. Before, everything was fine.

What can I do?

Comment: `Apr 05 11:25:10 archlinux-vm vboxdrv.sh[359]: vboxdrv.sh: failed: modprobe vboxpci failed. Please use 'dmesg' to find out why.` did you try to modprobe vboxpci by hand ? Did you reboot your machine after updating so that the new kernel is loaded ?

Comment: `$ modprobe vboxpci` -->  `modprobe: FATAL: Module vboxpci not found in directory /lib/modules/5.6.2-arch1-2`

Comment: yes, I did reboot

Comment: I have updated and rebooted the machine again, see my edit for the changes

Comment: Ok, can you please post the result of the `modprobe vboxpci` and the result of `uname -a` please , once rebooted please

Comment: Looks like a mismatch between your kernel version and the version of the driver. You upgrade with `pacman -Syu` right ?

Comment: `$ modprobe vboxpci` is still the same as in the earlier comment. `$ uname -a` --> `Linux archlinux-vm 5.6.2-arch1-2 #1 SMP PREEMPT Sun, 05 Apr 2020 05:13:14 +0000 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Comment: yes, I am using `pacman -Syu`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106425/discussion-between-pierre-alain-toret-and-maddingl).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First thing you don't need the `virtualbox-host-modules-arch` package as you are running a guest.
You can also simply disable vboxdrv, if you don't want to uninstall it, with `systemctl disable vboxdrv`

Then you need to enable the `vboxservice` with `systemctl enable --now vboxservice`, it should return without error.

And last it seems there's a [bug](https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/61183) in the Arch packaging, so you need to install `xf86-video-vmware` so that X can detect the card exposed by the VirtualBox host properly.

Answer (score 0):

Install new DKMS:

```
dkms install --no-depmod vboxhost/7.0.8_OSE -k 6.2.12-zen1-1-zeinstall new dkms
```